# Parsing XML with Python and exporting to excel

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an XML file that looks like below:

```
     <Result name="1">
       <point>
       <objects>
          <object>
             <path>
                <node>A</node>
                <node>a</node>
                <node>B</node>
                <node>b</node>
                <node>C</node>
                <node>c</node>
                <node>D</node>
                <node>d</node>
             <path/>
          <object/>
          <object>
             <path>
                <node>A</node>
                <node>a</node>
                <node>B</node>
                <node>b</node>
                <node>C</node>
                <node>c</node>
                <node>D</node>
                <node>d</node>
               </path>
            <object/>
         <objects/>
      <Result/>
   <Results/>
```

I would like a python script that can export to excel in the format below:

[image]

I would really appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the python documentation. From https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
 root = tree.getroot()
```

I also recommend checking out https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

As far as the logic for manipulating the data, unless you absolutely know the specific order/structure of the xml file, you may run in to problems as there is nothing (as far as I can tell) differentiating `<node>A</node>` from `<node>a</node>` or limiting the number of nodes to exactly 8, so you would need to check that stuff and other things of that nature to make sure things end up lined up correctly in the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to transform this XML (?) to HTML table and then load the HTML table to excel.

For example (using BeautifulSoup library):

```
data = '''
     <Result name="1">
       <point>
       <objects>
          <object>
             <path>
                <node>A</node>
                <node>a</node>
                <node>B</node>
                <node>b</node>
                <node>C</node>
                <node>c</node>
                <node>D</node>
                <node>d</node>
             <path/>
          <object/>
          <object>
             <path>
                <node>A</node>
                <node>a</node>
                <node>B</node>
                <node>b</node>
                <node>C</node>
                <node>c</node>
                <node>D</node>
                <node>d</node>
               </path>
            <object/>
         <objects/>
      <Result/>
   <Results/>'''

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub(r'<(.*?)/>', r'</\1>', data), 'html.parser')

num_objects = len(soup.select('object'))
num_nodes = len(soup.select_one('object').select('node')) // 2

print('<html><table border=1>')
print('<tr>')
print('<th>Result</th>')
for i in range(num_objects):
    print('<th colspan={}>Object</th>'.format(num_nodes))
print('</tr>')

for result in soup.select('Result[name]'):
    print('<tr>')
    print('<td rowspan=2>{}</td>'.format(result['name']))

    nodes = result.select('node')
    for node in nodes[::2]:
        print('<td>' + node.text + '</td>')
    print('</tr>')
    print('<tr>')
    for node in nodes[1::2]:
        print('<td>' + node.text + '</td>')
    print('</tr>')
print('</table></html>')
```

This prints:

```
<html><table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Result</th>
<th colspan=4>Object</th>
<th colspan=4>Object</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan=2>1</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>C</td>
<td>D</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>C</td>
<td>D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
</table></html>
```

In Firefox, it looks:

[image]

Loading the data to LibreOffice Calc is easy (should be easy in Excel too):

[image]